TypeError: _reactQuery.QueryClient is not a constructor, @tanstack/react-query migration to v5 in jest tests
I migrated my @tanstack/react-query package to version 5 and followed all the steps of the breaking changes in the doc, but now when I run the jest tests I get the following error:
TypeError: _reactQuery.QueryClient is not a constructor

After trying to find a solution to it for hours, I could still not fix that error.
Has anyone else encountered this issue when migrating to v5 and managed to fix it?
import { QueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";

export const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      retry: 0,
    }
  },
});



But it works when you run the application? Looks like Jest is somehow using a different version of react-query

I decided to downgrade react-query back to version 4
